# I have a list of numbers above my Twitter-bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a `.carousel` on my twitter-bootstrap page. However there are a list of numbers that have appeared at the top of this element. Have a look at the top left corner of the attached image.

[image: my carousel with numbers at the top]

Here is the HTML code I have used:

```
<div class="conatiner-fluid">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="workcarousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel indicators">
            <li data-target="workcarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="workcarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="workcarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/work1.png">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p> Wordpress Portfolio</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/work2.png">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p> Maths Game </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/work3.png">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p> Responsive landing page</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#workcarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only"> Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#workcarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only"> next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying below style to your ordered list.

```css
style="list-style-type:none"
```